# Replace Array with a Different Array in Object Property in Redux Without Mutating

Tags: redux, react-redux

I have a redux state that's not as flattened as it is recommended that a redux state be. However, I have all of my CRUD operations fully functioning except one.

My state is formatted like this:

```
{
  id: "adsfli23r89hdasd"
  items: [
    {...stuff},
    {...otherStuff},
    {...differentStuff}
  ]
  lastUpdated:"2017-04-26T22:14:44.204Z"
}
```

I have a reducer, and I want to be able to replace the entire items array with a new value, but can't get it to work.

So something like this works:

```
return {
  ...state,
  items: [],
  lastUpdated: action.lastUpdated
}
```

But this does not:

```
return {
  ...state,
  items: action.myNewStateArray,
  lastUpdated: action.lastUpdated
}
```

where `action.myNewStateArray` is passed into the reducer through an action creator and is equal to something like:

```
[
  {...newStuff},
  {...newOtherStuff}
]
```

NOTE: `action.myNewStateArray` may have a different number of items and should be assumed to be completely different than the existing state.

Anyone know how I can get this to work? Thanks in advance!

UPDATE: Here's a gist with some more in-depth code, https://gist.github.com/sambrodie/76e99e08932cd77765dc25f094a51fbf

Comment: does return `return {
  ...state,
  items: [...action.myNewStateArray],
  lastUpdated: action.lastUpdated
}` work ?

Comment: Hey @vincenttaing, tried that and it doesn't seem to work :/. Items is a multidimensional array if that makes a difference.